# How I install Haskell under Linux ? - a bug in the official doc?

Tags: c++, linux, haskell, c++11

I would like to start with Haskell and I am at [this page](http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html), the page clearly says

> Get and install GHC 7.6.3 prior to building the platform

but if you click the [link to GHC 7.6.3](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3) ( the published version at this point in time )

> Stop!
>
> For most users, we recommend installing the Haskell Platform instead of GHC. The current Haskell Platform release includes a recent GHC release as well as some other tools (such as cabal), and a larger set of libraries that are known to work together.

What should I do ?
I'm interested in using Haskell in conjunction with C++11, so I'm particularly interested in building the interpreter and the essential libraries from the source and what is the best way to use Haskell in general, if Haskell provides more than 1 version of the interpreter and what are all the possible solutions, this informations do not help me in finding a way.

I'm under Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 and I would like to know what is the best way to start with Haskell .

Comment: Why aren't you using http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=haskell-platform, linked from that page?

Comment: @LouisWasserman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317458/how-i-install-haskell-under-linux-a-bug-in-the-official-doc?noredirect=1#comment30319899_20317527

Comment: GHC - the Haskell compiler that pretty much _everyone_ uses right now - is written in Haskell, so you need a Haskell compiler to compile GHC. Which means, you'll probably need GHC. If you wanted to go at this the hard way, you could go back to some haskell compiler that was written in C - possibly an early version of GHC, not sure though - and work your way up from there. That's gonna take you a long time though. Like, really long.

Comment: If you want absolute control over your GHC installation, quchen recently wrote up a nice guide for using any old GHC to bootstrap a new installation. [It's on his github.](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/zero_to_local_ghc.md) This will install just the compiler GHC, and then you will need to pull in whatever libraries you are going to use with the package manager `cabal`. The Haskell Platform is basically a pre-packaged GHC together with some good libraries. Note that following the guide I linked is a very advanced way, and I definitely do not recommend it for a beginner.

Comment: @Cubic is this the way Haskell binds to C++11 ? usually a given scripting language is capable of extending C/C++ functionality while acting as a common library, a compiled object, this is the way it happens with Haskell ?

Comment: Haskell doesn't bind to C++11 at all. It can bind to C, and you can write a C compatibility layer in C++. Or, you can generate C++ code from Haskell. Two completely different scenarios. In neither case do you need particular control over the Haskell compiler; you certainly don't need to build that from source.

Comment: @user2485710 Haskell isn't a scripting language. There's an interpreter supplied with GHC, but it's primary use is for development purposes. Normally, you'd compile your Haskell code to an executable. There's a FFI to interact with C code, there's no direct way to interact with C++ code. You can write a C bridge to your C++ code though and use that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout ok, so I can use Haskell as a C library and implement it inside my program ? Once I compile that, no other dependency is necessary ? For example I don't need to install the lua interpreter if my program uses lua internally because I already linked the lua interpreter as a library; is this a similar case ?

Comment: @user2485710: no, you can't "use Haskell as a library". You can perhaps create a library in Haskell and use that from C and thereby from C++. Or you can somehow run the Haskell interpreter in a shell that's controlled from a C++ program. But both would be really complicated and I don't see much use in either approach. If you want to use Haskell, why not do it properly and write _all your program_ in it? It's much easier to use libraries written in lower-level languages from a Haskell program than something the other way around.

Comment: @leftaroundabout because for what I have to do all the technologies/libraries are provided in C/C++ and I need a layer on top, a "scripting language", to let the user interact with my program, Haskell was interesting enough, especially because is strongly typed and uses "type classes" ( the equivalent of C++ concepts as I understand ), plus other neat things, other scripting languages do not even have a real typing system, so my focus was more on using a new language that looked promising to extend my program, but now I understand that the interpreter doesn't work as I thought it would ...

Comment: Well, you can certainly do something similar with Haskell, but it only works out properly if you really wrap all the libraries so you can use them _from Haskell_. Then, rather then having the user interact _to your program_ through Haskell, they _import your program as a Haskell library_. Either into GHCi, or to build their own specialised executable version of the program. But, it really doesn't seem like this is a feasible solution for your problem at hand. — Lua OTOH is specifically designed for this goal, so obviously it's much easier there. If you find its type system too weak – Python?

Comment: @user2485710 It's not impossible to use Haskell as an extension language, but the usual approach is to do pretty much everything in Haskell and bind to C libraries when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux source distribution of the Haskell Platform does not include GHC. So if you actually want to build everything from source, then you need GHC separately first.

But most people get the platform via a binary installer, or, on Linux, via their distribution. So you should check whether Ubuntu 13.10 has the Haskell Platform, and it seems it [does](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/haskell/haskell-platform), so I recommend you start from there.

Comment: I'm not using the packaged version that comes with the Ubuntu repository on purpose, I need to get my feet wet with any aspect of Haskell including building it from source because I need to know what it needs and how to create the bindings that I will need later on with C++11. So what I should download ?

Comment: You'll need a binary GHC to bootstrap GHC. So if you actually want to build from source, I'd suggest you install the Ubuntu ghc package, then try to use that to build ghc-7.6.3 from source, and then try to compile the Haskell Platform source distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out https://www.fpcomplete.com/.  The website has interactive tutorials and allows you to run haskell without having to install it on your machine.